# Decompose ts with odd starting month

Tags: r, time-series, xts

at the moment I try to get the seasonal-component of my data.
To do so I create a `ts` via `tk_ts` from a tibble of dates and value.
Unfortunately on of my data sets starts at 2011-07-01 and runs to 2018-05-01 (with missing data that I already filled with `pad` from the `padr` lib).

Since a `ts` with `frequency = 12` **has to** start at the first of January I can't model this data with a `ts`. So I tried to create a `xts` from my data and cast it to a `ts`, but either I can't make the frequency work or the data is off.

Here is my MWE:

```
library(tidyquant)
library(timetk)

raw_data <- tibble(Date = c(as.Date("2011-07-01"), as.Date("2011-08-01"),
                   as.Date("2011-09-01"), as.Date("2011-10-01"),
                   as.Date("2011-11-01"), as.Date("2011-12-01"),
                   as.Date("2012-01-01"), as.Date("2012-02-01")),
                  Value = c(1,4,1,4,1,4,1,4))
                  # And so on, till 2018-05-01 and with reasonable values

tk_ts(raw_data, select = Value, start = 2011, frequency = 12)
# Leads to:
# 
#      Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug
# 2011   1   4   1   4   1   4   1   4
#
# which is bad since my first date is 2011-07-01 not 2011-01-01.

xts_data <- xts(raw_data$Value, order.by = raw_data$Date, frequency = 12)
# xts_data Leads to, which is fine:
# 
# [,1]
# 2011-07-01    1
# 2011-08-01    4
# 2011-09-01    1
# 2011-10-01    4
# 2011-11-01    1
# 2011-12-01    4
# 2012-01-01    1
# 2012-02-01    4

as.ts(xts_data, start = start(xts_data), end = end(xts_data))
# Leads to:
# 
# Time Series:
# Start = 15156 
# End = 15371 
# Frequency = 1 
# [1] 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1
# [52] 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4
# [103] 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1
# [154] 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4
# [205] 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4
#
# Which is totaly bad since there are more than the original 8 values.

as.ts(xts_data, start = start(xts_data))
# Leads to:
# 
# Time Series:
#   Start = 15156 
# End = 15163 
# Frequency = 1 
# [1] 1 4 1 4 1 4 1 4
#
# Which is bad since the Frequency is off
#  and I need it to be ok for the decompose.

as.ts(xts_data, start = start(xts_data), end = end(xts_data), frequency = 12)
# Leads to:
# 
# Error in ts(coredata(x), frequency = frequency(x), ...) : 
#   formal argument "frequency" matched by multiple actual arguments

attr(xts_data, 'frequency') <- 12
as.ts(xts_data, start = start(xts_data))
# Leads to:
# 
# Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug
# 15156   1   4   1   4   1   4   1   4
#
# Which is as bad as the first example
```

So how can I generate a decompose (to get the seasonal component) of data that dose not start at the first of January?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a simple addition to your `start` argument specifying the month number as well (07 in this case).

```
raw_data <- tibble(Date = c(as.Date("2011-07-01"), as.Date("2011-08-01"),
                            as.Date("2011-09-01"), as.Date("2011-10-01"),
                            as.Date("2011-11-01"), as.Date("2011-12-01"),
                            as.Date("2012-01-01"), as.Date("2012-02-01")),
                   Value = c(1,4,1,4,1,4,1,4))
# And so on, till 2018-05-01 and with reasonable values

tk_ts(raw_data, select = Value, start = c(2011,07), frequency = 12)
```

This results in the following output:

```
tk_ts(raw_data, select = Value, start = c(2011,07), frequency = 12)
     Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
2011                           1   4   1   4   1   4
2012   1   4
```

Hope that helps with what you are trying to achieve in the subsequent steps.

Comment: looking good at first, but I'll have to test it in depth tomorrow, thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: If it worked, please accept the answer by clicking the tick mark next to your question. Thanks